# Are there rules in 5e for shooting into combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, ranged-attack

What rules govern "shooting into combat" -- that is making a ranged attack on an enemy who is partially obscured by other creatures.  I know that the rules regarding cover may give the enemy an AC bonus in this case.  Is there any risk of hitting an unintended target on a miss?

Comment: I'm undeleting this because the purpose of the [duplicate] functionality of the site is that *good* questions will be asked in multiple ways, and we actually want the duplicates. They make searching for answers more effective. So thank you for the well-titled and well-written duplicate! It is valuable to the site.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - Ok, I deleted it because I didn't think there was anything better my version added.  But... I missed the original because I was looking for "shooting" rather than "firing" so I guess you have a point.